# Truffle Ropsten Deployment Issues

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle

I just made some updates to my contracts and tried to redeploy them - but I'm getting this message, over and over again.

[image]

Its not even *attempting* any of the migrations - it just goes right to this message - and obviously, despite what its saying, everything is *not* up to date.

I also tried adding the `--reset` flag to my migration command - same result.

I also deleted the `build` folder and did everything again: re-compiled, then tried the migration again - same result:

`Everything is up to date` ...

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the build directory of Truffle or to add --reset to your command.

A compilation of the former contract is still there and Truffle is not aware of your changes.

Comment: Oh I did all those things - several times. I forgot to mention that in my question - but I'll update it now so people know I've done that. (thank you though!)

Comment: ok. And what about your migrations files ? Would you mind sharing them ? Maybe ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Truffle HDWallet Provider with an Infura node. If so, go in truffle.js (or truffle-config.js) and under the ropsten provider (under networks), try passing the Infura API URL with **https://**. So it should look like this:

```
// Inside truffle.js

// imports

module.exports = {
  ...

  networks: {
      ...

    ropsten: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(YOUR_MNEMONIC, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/YOUR_KEY")
      },
      network_id: 3
    }
  }
};
```